# How to add new methods to the jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, methods, jquery

Is there some way to add methods to jQuery's objects?

For example, I have jQuery object

```
a = $('div')
```

I'd like that every object which was assigned like that, would have particular method (`doSomething()`) so I could invoke it like

```
a = $('.foo')
a.doSomething()

b = $('.bar')
b.doSomething()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to add your function to the `$.fn` namespace. Please note that inside the function, `this` will refer to the jQuery object, not a DOM object.

```
$.fn.doSomething = function () {
    this.css('color', 'red');
};

$('#retk').doSomething();
```

​
[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LkPTf/)

Please read about [writing jQuery plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for additional guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

add it like

```
$.fn.doSomething = function(data){
    // data is the argument passed to doSomething
    return this.each(function(){
       var elem = $(this);
       //perform operation on elem
       // like to change background color use
       elem.css('background-color','red');

    });
}
```

Comment: I'd just point out that this will affect *any* jQuery object created.

Comment: @jAndy Updated answer, Can you please check and confirm if it's correct now.

Comment: `.css()` method is not a really good example here, makes the use of `.each()` pointless.